# How many types of pygame display?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning about pygame display.
Basic of setting display I knew is like this:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
```

but, I noticed I can add features in back like this:

```
pygame.FULLSCREEN
pygame.RESIZEABLE
pygame.DOUBLEBUF
```

Are there anything features I can add? (+Features)
pygame.

Comment: Just go look [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode). Those libraries would be worth nothing if they weren't properly documented, so they usually are, and you can learn a ton of interesting things if you dig in it.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is unclear, you wrote down three of options to the `flags` argument of the function in the pygame library, `pygame.display.set_mode()`. I expect you want to know **what they mean** and/or **what others are**:

**`pygame.FULLSCREEN`** does as expected and creates a **fullscreen display**.
**`pygame.RESIZEABLE`** also does as would be expected and **allows the display to be resized**. 
**`pygame.DOUBLEBUF`** has to do with **the render buffer** and is only really used in conjunction with a separate renderer like **pyOpenGL**.

Others include `NOFRAME` that gives a borderless display window, and `pygame.HWSURFACE` and `pygame.OPENGL` that are specific to those options.

Note that *in general*, these flag arguments are **not necessary** for most pygame applications, especially if you're beginning.

---

[This link to the pygame refrence documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) demonstrates the various options with `pygame.display.set_mode()`. On that website, you can find all the documentation for pygame if you ever needed it.